# 2y-blowfish hash keys in Python for shadow

Tags: python, bcrypt, blowfish

As I found out, `2a` shadow hash keys are deprecated because `2a` has implementation flaws. It's been corrected in 2011 and now `2y`-hashes are used widely on Linux systems.

I tried to find a Python library which calculates `2y`-hashes, but I failed. I searched at least two hours and had a look at all libraries available but every single library for Python only calculates `2a` hashes. The most of them are wrapper for the reference `bcrypt` from BSD but they only calculate `2a`-hashes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [passlib.hash.bcrypt](http://packages.python.org/passlib/lib/passlib.hash.bcrypt.html#passlib.hash.bcrypt) class from the [passlib](http://packages.python.org/passlib/) password hashing library supports the `2y` format. Note that you should also install [py-bcrypt](http://code.google.com/p/py-bcrypt/) as a dependency.